# Kendo.Grid Delete Acton does not invoke the Controller's method even though I'm doing the same as in telerik example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, kendo-grid, action

I have the following Kendo().Grid():

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TicketReportPropertyEntity>()
    .Name("TicketReportPropertyGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(c => c.PropertyName).Title("Property Name").EditorTemplateName("_PropertyNameEditor").Width(900);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Amount).Title("Amount").Format("{0:C}").Width(90);
        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(150);
    })
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("Databound").SaveChanges("SaveGrid").Edit("Edit"))
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create();
        toolbar.Save();
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Navigatable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        //.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(c => c.ID);
            model.Field(c => c.PropertyName);
            model.Field(c => c.Amount);
        })
        .Create(create => create.Action("AddTicketReportProperty", "TicketReportProperty").Data("GetData"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "TicketReportProperty", Model))
        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateTicketReportProperty", "TicketReportProperty"))
        .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("DeleteTicketReportProperty", "TicketReportProperty"))
    )
)
```

And my controller's method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteTicketReportProperty([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, TicketReportPropertyModel model)
{
   var result = new TicketReportPropertyModel().DeleteTicketReportProperty(model.ID);

    return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Here is a "SaveGrid" function:

```
function SaveGrid(e) {
    console.log("save")
    var rowsCount = e.sender.dataSource.data().length;
    var totalSum = 0;
    if (rowsCount > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
            totalSum += e.sender.dataSource.data()[i].Amount;
        }
    }
    var ticketAmount = $('#Ticket_Amount').val();
    console.log(ticketAmount);
    if (totalSum != ticketAmount) {
        console.log("failed");
        //show the popup
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

It should add, update and delete records. Now, I'm working on deleting the record. But the event does not call the controller.

I'm following telerik example [here](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing)

What am I missing?

Comment: You did remember to click to save button, right? If so: What happens in your events {{DataBound}}, {{SaveGrid}} and {{Edit}}?

Comment: Edit event is fired when "Add New Record" is clicked. That's how it works with that kind of settings. On Edit event, I populate combobox through Ajax call to controller. "SaveGrid" events is fired when "Save Changes" button is clicked from the toolbar. It validates the sum of the Amounts and `Update` event is firing calling controller's Update method

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not following exactly the example from telerik. When you create the Grid you're using an Entity *TicketReportPropertyEntity*, but in the Controller you are receiving a Model *TicketReportPropertyModel*. 
Make sure you create your Grid using the Model, not the Entity, as the example you're following.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TicketReportPropertyModel>()
```

Comment: It does not help :)

Comment: You've a custom _SaveGrid_ function. Please, show the code, because it seems that something is missing there.

Comment: I added SaveGrid function